# Android ReactNative callback to native

Tags: android, react-native, callback

I am currently working on developing a module of my Android native app to display widgets (written in react native). So basically I have an activity that contains that widget. The widget basically has its UI components (Texts, button, ...).

My question is: is there a way that when a user tabs on a button (in the react-native widget) an activity gets called in my native app? Maybe also pass a parameter to determine what activity (HOME_SCREEN, LISTSCREEN, MAPSCREEN,...)?

Any help will be highly appreciated or if you know of any link/document from which I can extract the information that will be great!.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is one topic that fits your looking well, it's Native Modules. 
Check it out from here
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android
and

https://shift.infinite.red/native-modules-for-react-native-android-ac05dbda800d

You can also pass the param (the activity name in this case ) to the native side too.
Hope it helps!